# How can I run binding of isaac afterbirth plus using wine?

Tags: 16.04, wine, games

I'm trying to play binding of Isaac afterbirth plus on Ubuntu 16.04 using wine.
I have the game installed but when I run it nothing happens, the cursor puts the "loading" sign for a bit but that's it. How can I fix this ?
Note that I can run binding of Isaac Rebirth on the same system just fine without any problems.
My wine version is 2.0.1 and I have wine mono version 4.8.1.
thank you for reading.

Comment: Why use Wine? This game is on Linux http://store.steampowered.com/app/401920/The_Binding_of_Isaac_Afterbirth/ if you own a Windows copy, you own a Linux copy too.

Comment: I didn't get it from steam. I got a windows copy from a DVD and I don't want to buy the game again so I want to play the windows version using wine.

Comment: All I see looking around is key versions, I don't see a Windows only DVD release of the game anywhere but it won't work anyway, see here https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34608 sounds like the same issue.